# Recibir URL en mi App, cuando se pulsa compartir en el Browser

Tags: android, android-studio, app, url

Cuando navego con el explorador por internet en el móvil, tengo la posibilidad de compartir la url, pulsando el botón `<` aparecen unas aplicaciones (Gmail, linkedin...)

1. ¿Como puedo hacer que aparezca mi aplicación? Cuando se pulsa compartir
2. ¿Como puedo recibir la url en un campo de mi app?

Gracias de antemano.

[image: Compartir URL]

[image: Compartir a traves de]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Como puedo hacer que aparezca mi aplicación al compartir?

Lo que deseas es algo similar a un Intent  Chooser

para esto tienes que agregar un [Intent-Filter](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) a la Activity principal de tu aplicación para recibir una Intent del tipo [ACTION_SEND](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) :

```
<activity android:name="ShareActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Esto lo puedes ver en la documentación [**Recepción de una intent implícita**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving), por ejemplo definiendo esto en `MainActivity`:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

de esta forma al compartir podrás ver tu aplicación como una opción para realizarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ¿Como puedo recibir la url compartida, en un campo de mi app?

Para recibir datos que previamente enviaste mediante un `Intent`, estos son recibidos en el método `onCreate()` usando el método `getIntent()`

```
 Intent intent = getIntent(); 
String urlCompartido = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

o simplemente:

```
 String urlCompartido  = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

Answer (score 3):

Intenta especificandole a una actividad que recibira `mimeType="text/plain"` en el manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ActividadLink">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Esto lo que quiere decir es que la `ActividadLink` sera el activity que se ejecutara cuando se comparta un link. Luego para obtener el link seria de esta manera:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
    if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
        String link = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            if (link!= null) {

                textBox.setText(link);
            }
    }
}
```